# How to get the formparam values in hosted target in apigee

Tags: apigee

How to get the formparam values which are set in assignmessage policy

```
<AssignMessage continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="add-formparams-3">
  <Add>
    <FormParams>
      <FormParam name="name">{request.queryparam.name}</FormParam>
      <FormParam name="zip">{request.queryparam.zipCode}</FormParam>
      <FormParam name="lang">{request.queryparam.lang}</FormParam>
    </FormParams>
  </Add>
  <AssignTo transport="http" type="request"/>
</AssignMessage>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var paramName = context.getVariable("request.queryparam.name");
var paramZip = context.getVariable("request.queryparam.zip");
var paramLang = context.getVariable("request.queryparam.lang");
```

or

```
var paramName = context.getVariable("request.queryparam.name");
var paramZip = context.getVariable("request.queryparam.zipCode");
var paramLang = context.getVariable("request.queryparam.lang");
```

Above are from  and below are from {request.queryparam.xxx}